# Upload multiple images to firebase then save image url to firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

Can someone assist me with revising the code so it will wait for the upload to finish then save the image urls to firestore? I'm new to async and await and can't seem to figure it out. The `fileDownloadUrl` is still empty even if I do the saving to firestore inside the `Promise.all(promises).then()`:

```
cxonst promises = [];
const fileDownloadUrl = [];

pictures.forEach(file => {
    const uploadTask = 
    firebase
    .storage()
    .ref()
    .child(`img/upl/${file.data.name}`)
    .put(file.uploadTask);
    
    promises.push(uploadTask);

    uploadTask.on(
        
        firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
        snapshot => {
            const progress = Math.round((snapshot.bytesTransferred / 
                 snapshot.totalBytes) * 100);
            
            if (snapshot.state === firebase.storage.TaskState.RUNNING) {
                console.log(`Progress: ${progress}%`);
            }
        },
        error => console.log(error.code),
        async () => {
            const downloadURL = await 
            uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
            fileDownloadUrl.push(downloadURL);
            }
        );
    });

    Promise.all(promises)
    .then(() => {
        db
        .collection("properties")
        .add({
            timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
            title: title,
            description: description,
            pictures: fileDownloadUrl,
            user: user.uid
        })
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you are waiting for the promises of the `put` calls to complete, you're then using the `uploadTask.on()` to determine the download URL. Since this `on` is not part of the promise, there is no guarantee they're in sync.

A simpler and working approach should be:

```
const promises = pictures.map(file => {
  const ref = firebase.storage().ref().child(`img/upl/${file.data.name}`);
  return ref
    .put(file.uploadTask)
    .then(() => ref.getDownloadURL())
});

Promise.all(promises)
.then((fileDownloadUrls) => {
    db
    .collection("properties")
    .add({
        timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
        title: title,
        description: description,
        pictures: fileDownloadUrls,
        user: user.uid
    })
})
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: Great! This code is clean and works! Now, just need to wrap my head around this on how it works and where to get the progress event

Comment: You can still use the same `on` for measuring progress if needed.